# Twilio find out which user has joined the room

Tags: javascript, twilio

I used twilio in the past for 1-1 conversations without any problem but now I'm trying to put multiple users in the same room and I need to find out which user has just joined the room.

My UI is the following:
[image]

Logic to be applied:

1. The user enters the room and the "Main Webcam" is filled
2. When a new user connects to the room it must check which webcam belongs to him and turn it on
3. When an existing user disconnects from the room it must turn off his webcam
4. If the user clicks in any webcam it must clone into the "Main Webcam"

I'm using Twilio JS and this is my code:

```
Twilio.Video.connect(accessToken,
{
    name: roomId,
    audio: true,
    preferredVideoCodecs: ['H264', 'VP8']
}).then(function(room)
{
    Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack().then(function(track)
    {
        /*
         * After joining the room immediatelly assings the user webcam into the 'Main Webcam'
         * Works great
         */
        $('.main-webcam').append(track.attach());
    });

    room.on('participantConnected', function(participant)
    {
        /*
         * Somehow here I need to be able to get a parameter called 'userId' which I'll use to apply some login into my 'Small Webcams'
         */
    }),

    room.on('participantDisconnected', function(participant)
    {
        /*
         * Somehow here I need to be able to get a parameter called 'userId' which I'll use to apply some login into my 'Small Webcams'
         */
    });
});
```

How do I assign extra data/parameters to the variable `participant`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**.

When creating the Access Token through PHP I was using a random value assigned to the `identity` variable, as such:

```
$identity   = str_random(40) . '-' . time() . '-' uniqid();
$token      = new AccessToken($this->twilio['sid'], $this->twilio['key'], $this->twilio['secret'], 3600, $identity);
```

And I found out that the `identity` value can be catch with javascript, therefore I switched from a random value to the user id.

```
$identity   = $myUserId;
$token      = new AccessToken($this->twilio['sid'], $this->twilio['key'], $this->twilio['secret'], 3600, $identity);
```

Now i'm able to use it on Twilio JS and find out who's the user that just joined the room:

```
room.on('participantConnected', function(participant)
{
    console.log(participant.identity); // Retrieves the user id set on the Access Token
}),
```